# Ajax post getting "cancelled"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax post, but it's getting cancelled. I just made a `test.php` file which is just supposed to `echo 'test';` value.

This is how my ajax script looks like:

```
function loadAd(date) {
    var ajax_url = '<?=URL?>components/ajax/grab_ads.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: ({
            date : date
        }),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data > 0) {
                $('.advert').fadeIn("fast");
            }       
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert('Nastala chyba. ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

The function is called, I tried console logging it. The variable is passed okay as well. This is what I'm getting in chrome network tab. [screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/de64y1.jpg)

Other than that I am quite helpless.

Edit: I call the function like this:

```
$datum = Date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

$adl .= '<script type="text/javascript">
              loadAd(\''.$datum.'\');
         </script>';
```

Comment: Can you expand the entry in the network tab to see what the returned headers are?

Comment: @michael sure, here you go [link](http://i40.tinypic.com/2wp8c9i.png)

Comment: So when you call the Request Url manually in browser the test value is returned all right? Just checking. Anything in the Response Tab (probably not)?

Comment: i think the url might be wrong or your grab_ads.php script returns an error. thats why the success function wont be called

Comment: And the requested domain is the same as the one you are on?

Comment: Please show how you call the `loadAd()` function.

Comment: Well I don't think it's about the loadAd() function since the request is actually triggered, it is just not answered.

Comment: @bouscher yes, I am on the same domain. Nothing in the response tab, and yes, the php file works when checked manually

Comment: @bouscher I know, I tried '<?=URL?>' + 'components/ajax/grab_ads.php'; already

Comment: You still didn't answer what happens, when you actually call the Request URL manually in the browser.

Comment: @bouscher I did, two posts above or so, it works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see that. My bad.

Comment: Try to leave the common brackets () away around the data, just {date:date}

Comment: @bouscher no problem buddy, I tried removing the brackets, did not help unfortunately

Comment: @bouscher - in reference to your earlier comment, it _could_ have been about how `loadAd()` is called, because if it is called from e.g., a submit or anchor click handler then the event's default behaviour could interfere with the ajax submit.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are right of course. I said "I don't think", which doesn't mean "It is not". It acually seems that it is about the way he calls the function judging from what I see after the dit. I though it was called after jQuery(document).ready(function(){

Comment: @bouscher - Yes, I know you didn't say "it is not", no problem there. I was just explaining why I asked to see the function call.

Comment: @nnnnnn Agreed, absolutely agreed, sorry for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax requests are getting cancelled without being sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent)

Comment: Try solution mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54289161/784542

Answer (score 14, accepted):

we were making the ajax request from a link, and not preventing the link from being followed. So if you are doing this in an onclick attribute, make sure to return false; as well

```
 function loadAd(date) {
  var ajax_url = '<?=URL?>components/ajax/grab_ads.php';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: ({
        date : date
    }),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data > 0) {
            $('.advert').fadeIn("fast");
        }       
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert('Nastala chyba. ' + errorThrown);
    }
 });
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: or use `preventDefault();` at the start of function.

Comment: @NilotpalBarpujari,Ya,I think preventDefault() is the best method,Thanks

Comment: @shin how do I call the prevent default? Is it bound to an object? because the return false didn't help.

Comment: @InsaneSVK,If you call function onclick ,return false; only works,I think

Comment: @shin my function is called by refreshing the page, not onclick though :(

Comment: @shin I've edited the first post so you can see how exactly I'm calling the function. This piece of code is referenced in my header.tpl file, right after <body> begins.

Comment: try putting in async:false in your ajax request. This may break sth else, but try this if you want this to be the default action. The ajax requests are usually canceled when the browser starts navigating away from the page you are on.

Comment: @theshadowmonkey the async made it go from cancelled to pending, the pending is endless it seems

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `HTML element` by whose event the **AJAX** call is getting *triggered*.

If it's an input button, ensure it should be of type 
`button' <input type="button" />` and use `return` statement.

If it's an `anchor` tag, try using return statement: return either `true` or `false`.

Ensure page doesn't get refreshed on completion of the **AJAX** call. If you use input field of type submit, it will submit the form and lead to page refreshed, and the request gets canceled.