# Ajax call in loop: Ajax requests getting cancelled except last

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one ajax call in a loop as shown below.

```
reloadSetupAndRecurringAvailable = function( objDiscountRow ) {

    var intProductId = objDiscountRow.find('.product-id').val();
    var strUrl = '/?module=contract_setup_products-new&action=get_setup_and_recurring_available';

    $.ajax( {
    url: strUrl,
    data: { 'product_id': intProductId },
    success: function( response ) {
        fltSetupAvailable       = parseFloat( response.data.fltSetupAvailable );
        fltRecurringAvailable   = parseFloat( response.data.fltRecurringAvailable );

        objDiscountRow.find('.setup-available').text( fltSetupAvailable + '%' );
        objDiscountRow.find('.recurring-available').text( fltRecurringAvailable + '%' );
    }
} );

reloadDiscountProducts = function() {

    $('.discount-row').each( function() {
        reloadSetupAndRecurringAvailable( $(this) );
    } );
}

reloadDiscountProducts();
```

When the code executes, in the network tab the last ajax call shows successful and all the previous calls show in `canceled` status. [image: ajax in loop]

As per my findings it is due to asynchronization. The ajax request can take any time. How can I fix the code so that all the requests will be in completed status?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You aren't using async/await or promises here. So the tags were misleading

Comment: @Liam can you explain how: a) closures effect this question b) how closures would cause previous calls to cancel?

Comment: How *else* are you calling `reloadDiscountProducts`?  Is it from a button/link click?  Is this relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16585362/2181514

Comment: Closures affect this because `objDiscountRow` will mutate as the each changes. This is a classic mutation issue. Though the OP hasn't given anywhere near an [mcve] so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I think I need to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here

Comment: I fail to see how promises are going to help here?

Comment: @Liam I stand corrected, it would not be cancelled by the server, it would be a 503 (or similar)

Comment: @Liam - Using promise I will not call next iteration unless the current ajax call completes. If I do so I think the issue will be resolved. Checking how promises works...

Comment: No, that's not what promises do. Promises do not block. I would seriously advise you to read the duplicate I tagged as I'm reasonably sure that's what you're getting at.

Comment: I'd also suggest you read up on [asynchronicity in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/542251)