# Getting random response on hitting the POST API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, api, rest

[image]

I am getting different response on hitting the same API. Sometimes its 200, and sometimes its showing cancelled.
When I am hitting the API from Postman, its working absolutely fine but when I am hitting API from the js file, its showing this error in the network tab.
Tried using Fetch but still facing the same issue.

Here is my API code

```
using PostQuestion.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace PostQuestion.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        public string conString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-DO57SLF\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=doubtdb;Integrated Security=True";
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(LoginResponse))]
        public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequest login)
        {
            LoginResponse res = new LoginResponse();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login.Username))

            {
                res.Success = false;
                res.Message = "Username can not be empty";
                return Ok(res);

            }
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login.Password))
            {
                res.Success = false;
                res.Message = "Password can not be empty";
                return Ok(res);
            }

            try
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                con.Open();

                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    String Username = login.Username.Trim();
                    String Password = login.Password.Trim();
                    if (Username.Contains(" "))

                    {
                        res.Success = false;
                        res.Message = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        return Ok(res);

                    }
                    if (Username.Contains('=') && Username.Contains("or"))
                    {
                        res.Success = false;
                        res.Message = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        return Ok(res);
                    }
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spchecklogin", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Username;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int getcount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Count"].Value);
                    con.Close();
                    if (getcount == 1)
                    {
                        res.Success = true;
                        res.Message = "Login Successful!";
                        return Ok(res);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.Success = false;
                        res.Message = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        return Ok(res);
                    } 
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    res.Success = false;
                    res.Message = "Unable to Login";
                    return Ok(res);
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                res.Success = false;
                res.Message = "Unable to Login" + ex;
                return Ok(res);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my js code:

function Login() {

```
var username=document.getElementById("Email").value;
var password=document.getElementById("Password").value; 

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var raw = JSON.stringify({"Username":username,"Password":password});
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         alert(this.responseText);
     }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "https://localhost:44393/login", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(raw);
```

}

Comment: When you navigate to a new page, AJAX requests are cancelled. It is likely you are navigating between pages. Click `All` next to `XHR`.

Comment: In the ALL tab, everything shows 200 status except the login API
And both Gordan and GORDAN will be allowed since they don't contain '=' sign

Comment: `In the ALL tab, everything shows 200 status except the login API` Yes. The point I am making is that you are likely moving to a new page. This causes the AJAX requests to be cancelled. I don't have a different way to word that, unfortunately.

Comment: But why is `gordon=` not allowed as a username? What is special about `=` and `or`?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585157/ajax-post-getting-cancelled/16585362 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent ?

Comment: It worked after chaning the type to button
Thanks a lot @mjwills

Comment: Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issue
Earlier my button type was submit due to which the page was getting redirected
After changing the type to button, everything is working fine
Thanks everyone for your precious time.