# Ajax not accepting CORS(preflight) response

Tags: ajax, web-services, cors, http-post, preflight

I am using simpleCORSFilter.java for handling CORS request, which is working fine for other request but somehow, it is not working for AJAX POST request.

simpleCORSFilter.java

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,X-Requested-With,X-Requested-by, Content-Type, Accept,Session");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
                    console.log(' data : '+data);

                },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown:');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

After sending the preflight response it just stops working(doesn't shutdown server, but it is like just hanging there without any response), and if I try to request anything else then, it will break the connection and respond following

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Server Log :

```
----------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://localhost:9092/services/searchCMS/
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: OPTIONS
Content-Type: 
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, sdch], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], access-control-request-headers=[content-type], access-control-request-method=[POST], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Type=[null], dnt=[1], host=[localhost:9092], origin=[http://localhost:3000], referer=[http://localhost:3000/report], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36]}
--------------------------------------
2016-08-12 09:50:48.912  INFO 6408 --- [nio-9092-exec-1] o.a.c.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor  : Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 200
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Allow=[POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD], Date=[Fri, 12 Aug 2016 07:50:48 GMT], Content-Length=[0]}
--------------------------------------
```

I don't understand where exactly is the problem , Ajax part or Web Service part ? 
I have read so many blogs and stackoverflow answers, but I was not able to solve this problem.It just simply throws error after after getting preflight response from the web service.I don't know why ? may be I am missing something, which you experts can point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling this Ajax request on a button click, but I had forgotten to return on that click event. I found this solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10576567/2147560)

solution 1: you can return false on click() function

```
return false ; // for onClick funciton
```

solution 2: you can prevent using defaults

```
e.preventDefault();       //  e is the onclick event parameter
```