# Redirecting from https to http?

Tags: ajax, nginx, https, fullcalendar, http-status-code-301

Strange problem here.  I use FullCalendar to initiate an ajax request to an endpoint on my server. Endpoint is:

`https://my_website/events/?start=2019-03-31&end=2019-05-12&_=1555698739056`

Note that it is explicitly https. However, when I initiate a request (that is, when Fullcalendar initiates a request), I get a 301 and a redirect to a non-https endpoint:

`http://my_website/events?start=2019-03-31&end=2019-05-12&_=1555698739056`

which fails because the page is loaded over https.

[image]

The endpoint works fine - when i load it into the browser I get the expected json output (via https). There are other ajax requests happening on this page that work correctly, and I successfully do the exact same thing with Fullcalendar elsewhere on this site (to another endpoint). It's just this one scenario that is behaving unexpectedly.

Probably noteworthy is this sits in a docker container behind nginx reverse proxy / load balancer; site config is pretty simple:

```
upstream docker {
    server localhost:8701;
    server localhost:8702;
  }

server {
    server_name my_website;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://docker;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      # proxy_set_header                HTTP_Country-Code $geoip_country_code;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = my_website) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name my_website;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And nginx log of the request is like this:

> 134.124.11.91 - - [19/Apr/2019:13:49:49 -0500] "GET /events/?start=2019-04-28&end=2019-06-09&_=1555699678658 HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "https://my_website" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"

Does anyone see something I'm missing that would be causing this strange 301 redirect to a non-https endpoint?

Comment: There's nothing in your nginx config that could cause this redirect. Probably it's your endpoint initiating redirect because request is proxied via HTTP. To confirm, I recommend adding $upstream_status variable to log_format. If it will be equal to 301, then I am right. It probably can be solved by using https in proxy_pass or changing endpoint code.

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

This would appear to happen because you're not using canonical URLs, whereas your backend is enforcing such URLs through these `301` redirects, whereas it is not actually aware of the canonical address scheme.

---

## Solution

- Best solution would be to fix your ***front-end*** code to always use canonical URLs.  E.g., in the examples you provide, there's a difference in whether or not a trailing slash is present in your API endpoint.
- You should probably configure your ***back-end*** to be properly aware that it's being accessed through `https`, e.g., add something like the following next to all your other `proto_set_header` directives in your nginx that terminates https and passes the traffic to the backend:

  ```
  proto_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
  ```

---

## Other thoughts

- Another solution would be to configure http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect to properly recognise the local `Location` headers returned by your backend, and convert them on-the-fly as needed; however, the prior two options are probably a better approach in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, but 1) I don't see where there's a difference between trailing slashes and non-trailing slashes in my question; what endpoint doesn't have a trailing slash? 2)  explicitly settting the x-forwared-proto header did not help; and 3) I've played with proxy_redirect a bit, but to no avail. Any specific advice on how to use it?

Comment: (1), Your question has `https://my_website/events/?` and then `http://my_website/events?` — the original request has a trailing slash, the redirect doesn't.  (3), the first parameter for proxy_redirect would probably be `http://my_website/`, the second, `https://my_website/`; of course, this depends on your original question being correct, as the first part has to be an exact match to what's produced by your backend in its `Location` replies.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, because your screenshots are a bit conflicting, but here goes:

In your inspector screenshot we see one request to https (which is cancelled) and one to http (which is blocked due to mixed protocols). The hint is in the cancelled one, **being cancelled means there was no redirect there, but that the browser decided it no longer needed the request**. There are several previous questions that had similar issues, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24062160/11415228) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent) two examples.

One reason why a request gets canceled is if the button/input/link you use to change the date of your FullCalendar is not just doing an ajax request but also doing a second http request (because of a wrapping form, href, etc). You have not included your html and JavaScript of your FullCalendar implementation, so I do not know this for sure, but check that you do not have a form surrounding the input element, or if you wrote your own event handler do the following.

```
function(e){
  e.preventdefault(); 

  .... // your date switching code here 

  return false;
}
```

If you use a link with an onclick attribute, make sure you add `...(yourcode);return false;` at the end.

**Important:** If my theory is right, this means the line from your log doesn't actually correspond to the same thing we see in the inspector and is in fact a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, not the other way around. This would be hard to see because nginx does not include the request protocol in the log by default.