# What happens to a script on the server side when HTTP request gets cancelled?

Tags: php, http, nginx, fpm

I'm curios if a script gets aborted or it keeps running on the server side when I cancel a request from the client side, e.g. using browser:

[image]

Comment: That will very much depend on the server…

Comment: @deceze that's why I added tag "nginx"

Comment: add logging in the script and find out

Comment: Are you sure those requests were cancelled manually using the browser? There can be a couple of reasons, check [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools) or [jQuery Ajax requests are getting cancelled without being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent).

Comment: @IvanShatsky yes, I'm sure it's me who cancels them and I'm concerned with the negative impact it could produce

Comment: They will run until complete, but the output back to the client is lost.